# Is there any existing tool to monitor the process and restart if it crash?

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring

I am looking for existing tool to monitor the process and restart if it crashes in Ubuntu. It would be best if it can alert me when the process being restarted via Email or Slack.

Comment: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: There's a lot of ways to do that. The simpler is something like `while true; do process; script-to-send-alerts "The process died, restarting" ; done`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty open-ended question.  Monit, SupervisorD, systemd, Runit, Upstart can all do this, then you get to monitoring tools like Sensu, Nagios, DataDog; and auto-remediation tools like Neptune.io.  Or a simple Cron that watches for the process to die and restarts / notifies. Tons of options. The right answer will depend on your needs, environment, and budget.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I will look each of these tools and return. ^^

Answer (score 2):

You can use [monit](https://github.com/arnaudsj/monit) to monitor your running processes. It can monitor other things like: files, directories and filesystems.